# Is $\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ logically valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

There is a claim that I'd like to proof. It states that If $\vdash_K\mathcal{B}$ then there is a wf $\mathcal{C}$ that is the closure of the conjunction of some axiom $K$ such that $\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid.

Notation: $K$ is first-order theorem and $\mathcal{L}$ is the first-order language.

Here is my attempt: Assume $\vdash_K \mathcal{B}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is true in every denumerable model $M$ of $K$. In other words, $\mathcal{B}$ is true for an arbitrary interpretation $M$ of $\mathcal{L}$ for which all the axioms of $K$ are true. Now here comes my first question:

1. Does that mean that there exists $n$ axioms that are used to proof $\mathcal{B}$?

Assume (1.) is allowed. Let these axioms be $\mathcal{C}_i$, where $i = 1, \cdots n$ and consider $\mathcal{C}_1 \wedge \dotsc \wedge \mathcal{C}_n$. Since they are axioms, the conjunction of axioms is still true in $M$. Hence, by denoting $\mathcal{C}$ as the closure of $\mathcal{C}_1 \wedge \dotsc \wedge \mathcal{C}_n$, we have $\models_M\mathcal{C}$.Now, my last questions are:

2. If question 1 is allowed, can I conclude that $\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid? The reason why I thought I can do this is because of the consequence of deduction theorem. We have $\mathcal{C} \vdash_K \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a closed wf, so $\vdash_K \mathcal{C} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$. Hence by Gödel's completeness theorem, $\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid. However, this is true in predicate calculus (so $K$ has no proper axiom). Should I separate the case when $K$ is a predicate calculus and $K$ is not a predicate calculus?
3. If question 2 is true, can I prove the claim without separating these two cases?

Comment: What precisely is the *definition* of $\vdash_K B$?

Comment: it means that $\mathcal{B}$ is a (first-order) theorem of $K$, I believe. It's provable

Comment: Yes, the $\vdash$ symbol is usually meant this way. An alternate notation would be something like $K\vdash B$. So, according to your definitions, this should mean that there is a formal proof of $B$ from the axioms in $K$ using the logical rules of your proof system. But formal proofs are *finite*, so such a proof would only use finitely many axioms in $K$...

Comment: Right. So that answers my question number 1. But, how about question 2 and 3? Do I have to worry about them? I feel like I don't have to

Comment: I don't quite understand question 2, but I expect you are overthinking it. You start from $K\vdash B$. Then you argue that only finitely many axioms in $K$ are used to prove $B$. So this gives you a formula $C$, which is a conjunction of axioms in $K$, such that $C$ proves $B$. This would be written $C\vdash B$. So I am not sure what you mean when you write $C\vdash_K B$. But in any case, the deduction theorem does tell you that if $C\vdash B$ then $\vdash (C\rightarrow B)$. So depending on your definition of "logically valid", you might be done.

Comment: On the other hand, if "$A$ is logically valid" means $\models A$ (rather than $\vdash A$), then you would need the Soundness Theorem to get to $\models (C\rightarrow B)$.

Comment: To say that $\vdash_K B$ means that $B$ is derived from axioms of theory $K$. But a derivation is a *finite* sequence of formulas; thus, at most $n$ axioms $C_i$ can be used in the proof. Applying Deduction Th $n$ times, we get: $\vdash (C_1 \land \ldots \land C_n) \to B$. By Soundness, it follows that $\vDash (C_1 \land \ldots \land C_n) \to B$.