# Stuck on a proof in first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

The setting is first-order logic. I have to show the following:

> $\vdash_K \mathcal{B}$ if and only if there is a wf $\mathcal{C}$ that is the closure of the conjunction of some axioms of $K$ such that $\mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid.

This is what I have so far:

Let $K$ be a first-order theory and $\mathcal{B}$ some wf.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a wf that is the closure of the conjunction of some axioms of $K$ such that $\mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid. If $\mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid, we know that $\mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$ is a theorem of $K$. So $\vdash_K \mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$. Now the axioms of $K$ are theorems of $K$. By the conjunction introduction rule, the conjunction of some of those axiom is also a theorem of $K$. The closure of this conjunction is a theorem as well, since we may apply Generalization as many times as necessary to obtain the closure. Thus we know $\vdash_K \mathcal{C}$. From Modus Ponens it follows $\vdash_K \mathcal{B}$.

Is this a correct reasoning?

Now for the other direction of the proof, I do not know what to do. Should I assume there is no such $\mathcal{C}$ and show a contradiction? I suppose I cannot assume there is such a $\mathcal{C}$ but with $\mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$ not being logically valid and then derive a contradiction?.. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849811/is-mathcalc-rightarrow-mathcalb-logically-valid#comment7942072_3849811

Comment: Start with the definitions. What does it mean precisely to say $\vdash_K B$?

Comment: It means that $\mathcal{B}$ is a theorem of $K$. So there is a finite sequence of wfs $\mathcal{B}_1 , .. , \mathcal{B}_n$ such that $\mathcal{B}$ is $\mathcal{B}_n$ and each $\mathcal{B}_k$ is either a logical or proper axiom of $K$, a direct consequence by Generalization or a direct consequence by Modus Ponens.

Comment: Also, logically valid means it is true for every interpretation.

Comment: Ok so the main hint at this point is that the proof of $B$ from $K$ is *finite*, i.e., only uses finitely many wfs $B_1,\ldots,B_n$.

Comment: Alright, so I could argue that, since a proof is finite, it takes only a finite number of axioms of $K$ to prove $\mathcal{B}$. So I might as well say that there is a wf $\mathcal{C}$ that it the closure of the conjunction of these axioms, such that $\mathcal{C} \vdash_K \mathcal{B}$. (closure is allowed by Generalization). Then perhaps I can use Deduction Theorem to show $\vdash_K \mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$? But from this it does not immediately follow that $\mathcal{C} \implies \mathcal{B}$ is logically valid, right?

Comment: I am going to ask the same question that I did in the comments on the linked question above (which has clearly been asked by someone taking the same class or reading the same book). Why do you write $C\vdash_K B$? What does this mean precisely?

Comment: Oh I see! :) It is just for emphasis that it is in the theory $K$. This could be left out: just $\mathcal{C} \vdash \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Why re-posting it as a new user ?